# Nvidia GeForce Graphics Card Blue Screen of Death crash

Tags: graphics-card, crash, flash, bsod, nvidia-geforce

For the last couple of months, I get sudden crashes while watching a video.
It usually happens when I am skipping parts in a video - then my PC gets stuck, and after few seconds I get this popup message:

```
The following plugin has stopped working: Shockwave Flash
```

or something along those lines. 
Then I can choose to kill it or wait - but whatever I click causes my PC to crash and show the blue screen of death.

My video card is Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT, and my driver version is 6.14.12.7061.

I've analyzed the cause for the frequent blue screen crashes using WhoCrashed 3.2, and it says that the problem was caused by the `nv4_disp.dll` file:

```
crash dump file: C:\WINDOWS\Minidump\Mini061012-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: nv4_disp.dll (nv4_disp+0x2446BE) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1000008E (0xFFFFFFFFE0000001, 0xFFFFFFFFB8440925, 0xFFFFFFFFB0B91880, 0x0)
Error: KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M
file path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\nv4_disp.dll
product: NVIDIA Compatible Windows 2000 Display driver, Version 270.61 
company: NVIDIA Corporation
description: NVIDIA Compatible Windows 2000 Display driver, Version 270.61 
Bug check description: This indicates that a kernel-mode program generated an exception which the error handler did not catch.
This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem. 
A third party driver was identified as the probable root cause of this system error. It is suggested you look for an update for the following driver: nv4_disp.dll (NVIDIA Compatible Windows 2000 Display driver, Version 270.61 , NVIDIA Corporation).
```

I have tried to update the driver several times, but this problem doesn't go away.

I couldn't find any solution to this problem, and even though in the past I didn't have this issue, I couldn't find a good stable driver version that didn't have this problem (I've tried many old & new versions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some googling I found [this thread](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=207797) of people having the same problem. There, [disabling hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html#117123/help/help01.html#117123.) in Flash seems to help.

The other suggestion was to downgrade the driver, as it seems to be a conflict between newer Nvidia drivers and Flash Player.

---

You could at least ease some symptoms by enabling HTML5 video on the sites that support it (e.g. [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/html5), [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/extras/html5)). Or you could use something like FlashBlock to at least remind you before you load any Flash content.

Comment: This is assuming that the problem is tied to Flash Player. Is it always Flash that crashes or does it happen with other software too?

Comment: It is always Flash that crashes - YouTube videos, Facebook videos, Dailymotion, Metacafe, etc.

Comment: I came across this thread while googlling my problem some time ago, and I have tried to downgrade the driver's version to what they say is stable, but it would still crash when watching flash videos.

I turned off Hardware Acceleration in the Flash settings, I'll check if it solves anything. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Let's hope it helps. If not, you could at least ease some symptoms by enabling HTML5 video on the sites that support it (e.g. [YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/html5), [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com/extras/html5)). Or you could use something like FlashBlock to at least remind you before you load any Flash content.

Comment: The HTML5 video support works great, thanks for the tip. It's a big deal for me because I mostly watch videos on YouTube, and the HTML5 videos look and act the exact same thing, so it's great. I've tried watching flash videos on several sites and skipping parts (which usually causes the crash), and so far it has been stable. I hope it will stay stable from now on (fingers crossed). Thank you for your help!

Comment: _**Update:**_ It's been almost three weeks since you helped me, and so far it's working perfectly! I've been watching tons of videos on various sites, and everything is finally working properly, and I no longer need to restart my PC at all. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

My GTX 470 has been similarly unstable for a while. I was suspecting bad memory, but I came across [this post](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=215994&view=findpost&p=1332054) on Nvidia forums suggesting a mild overvolt to make the card more stable. I know the bug description says it's most likely not a hardware problem, but I'm putting my 2 cents here since it might at least help others.

In short, I used [MSI Afterburner](http://event.msi.com/vga/afterburner/download.htm) to increase the Core Voltage ~0.13mV above default, and my card has been much more stable since.

Your mileage may vary. Remember that more voltage likely means more heat and careless fiddling around may very well damage the card further. I used it as a last resort since my problem was bad enough that I would have had to ditch the card otherwise.

Comment: I doubt this is the case here, because in the past I didn't have any problems like this at all, and it occurs only when watching videos, not even when I play games on very high graphic settings.

Comment: Yes, seeing as it seems tied to Flash this answer is not applicable. The symptoms were similar though, mine was much more likely to crash during web browsing than graphics-intensive gaming, strangely enough.