# Suddenly Chrome is saying, "Shockwave has crashed". How can I fix this?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, flash

XP3,

Over the last few days Chrome is giving me the above message anywhere from 3 to 8 or so times a day.

I'm not sure it's related but my computer is freezing once or twice a day and I have to do a hard shut off and re-boot.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I had the exact same problem 6 months ago. It happened to me when watching videos, which use Flash. This is my post - hope it helps (turns out it was a problem in the Flash Player config): [**Nvidia GeForce Graphics Card Blue Screen of Death crash**](http://superuser.com/q/437899/138020).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there were 2 versions installed in chrome and one had to be disabled. Details here: http://www.howtogeek.com/103292/how-to-fix-shockwave-flash-crashes-in-google-chrome/

I did this and all seems well now for over a week.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall, then re-install Chrome.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure this is what will fix his problem (probably should be a comment).

Comment: @amiregelz  Okay.  But when I had the same problem, this is what fixed it for me.

Comment: If I uninstall and reinstall, will I lose all the windows I have open?

Comment: IIRC, it won't remember what windows you had open.  But it definitely will resync your bookmarks if you've [sync'ed them through a gmail account](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139).